# VBA function to delete a section of PowerPoint slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform

I'm trying to use the following VBA function to delete an entire section from a PPT. However, for some reason, when ever I type the code it returns an error saying about a "mismatch" error. Is anyone familiar with the following code and see if there is a bug with the VBA function itself?

```
ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Delete(1,True)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Delete 1,True`

Comment: It works now! Thank you!